Can Noachides say the name of God as the word 'Tetragrammaton' or say the names of the the four letters in Hebrew?
I ask because I found that there is a Muslim false prophet who goes by the name "Hashem" and G-d is very generic. If I wish to be specific as a Gentile am I permitted to say the word "Tetragrammaton" while praying or say the names of the four letters? And am I as a Gentile permitted to say "Amen" or variants.

Hello, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I find this question to be rather ambiguous, and not sure exactly what you are asking. Not sure if others will do any better

@RabbiKaii thanks for responding, the question is related to the prohibition against using the name of G-D in vain, which amounts to blasphemy which is against the Noahide laws as far as I understand

Try and read it from my point of view - you are asking quite a lot of questions in one, and some of them are not completely unabiguous. Say the word "Tetragrammaton"?

@Rabbi Just like it is forbidden for Gentiles to say the Aleph Dalet Nun Yud, I was asking if they can speak aloud the Greek word Tetragrammaton as a reference to G-D.
